# Riemann integral of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence, riemann-integration

Let $0\leq b<1$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k-1}}{k-\frac{1}{2}}, \quad x\in\mathbb{R}$$

- Show the the antiderivative $g:[-b,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and that
  $$g'(x)=\frac{2}{1-x^2}$$

for a $x \in [-b,b]$.

**So far**

I have shown that the sum converges uniformly on the interval $ [-b,b]$. After that I am completly stuck. It is my first time encountering anything quite like this. I know that if $g_n$ is a sequence of functions $g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ that are all Riemann integrable. If the sequence of functions converges uniformly to $g$, then $g$ is also Riemann integrable and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}g_n(t)dt=\int_{a}^{b}g(t)dt$$

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k - 1}}{k-\frac{1}{2}} = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k - 1}}{2k - 1}$$

Comment: @fwd so just take the limit then but what bounds on the integral?

Answer (score 1):

If you let $$g(x) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1},$$
$g$ is given by a power series that converges uniformly on $[-b, b]$, thus it is infinitely differentiable.

$$g'(x) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{2k-2} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k} = \frac{2}{1-x^2}$$ using the geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: why is is differentiable?

Comment: It is a power series. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Taylor Series of $\ln|1+x|$:
$$\ln|1+x|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{k+1}x^k}{k}$$
In this series, put $x\to -x$ and subtract. So,
$$\ln |1-x|=-x-\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac {x^3}{3}-\frac {x^4}{4}-...$$
If you subtract,
$$\ln|\frac {1+x}{1-x}|=2(x+\frac {x^3}{3}+\frac {x^5}{5}...)$$

Comment: No unfortunately not. I am not getting the approach.

Comment: See edited answer.